# Spring boot test - JUnit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mock, mockito

Como faço para resolver esse problema e executar o teste com JUnit no Spring boot?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CategoriaTest.class, 
                                  CategoriaService.class, CategoriaDao.class})
public class CategoriaTest {

    @Autowired
    private Service<Categoria> categoriaService;

    private Categoria categoria;

    @Test
    public void salvar() {
        try {
            categoria = new Categoria();
            categoria.setNome("Categoria 01");
            categoria.setAtivo(true);
            categoria.setMostrarMenu(false);
            categoriaService.add(categoria);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Erro...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoriaDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoriaDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:359) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1087) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:580) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:711) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:684) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Comment: O erro mostra que sua classe DAO tem dependências que não foram carregadas no contexto do seu teste, então você tem que carregá-las também, no caso, referente ao seu banco de dados. Qual seu objetivo com esse teste: um teste de integração, testar a camada de serviço ou testar a camada de persistência?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes utilizar uma abordagem com mocks:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoriaTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Service<Categoria> categoriaService;

    @Mock
    private CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;// Ou DAO

    private Categoria categoria;

    @Test
    public void salvar() {

        categoria = new Categoria();
        categoria.setNome("Categoria 01");
        categoria.setAtivo(true);
        categoria.setMostrarMenu(false);

        Mockito.when(categoriaDAO.salvar(categoria)).thenReturn(categoria);

        assertThat(categoriaService.add(categoria)).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(categoria);

    }

}
```